# Replacement CompareTo () in C ++ (Visual Studio 2012)

Tags: string, visual-c++, c++-cli

I was looking at examples of comparisons of strings but I need use something like this:

```
String^ MyString = "Hello World";
String^ OtherString = "Hello World!";
int MyInt = MyString->CompareTo(OtherString);
Console::WriteLine( MyInt );
```

This example displays 1 to the console.

---

*All overloads of the String.CompareTo method perform culture-sensitive and case-sensitive comparisons by default. No overloads of this method are provided that allow you to perform a culture-insensitive comparison. For code clarity, it is recommended that you use the String.Compare method instead, specifying CultureInfo::CurrentCulture for culture-sensitive operations or CultureInfo::InvariantCulture for culture-insensitive operations.*

---

But the function CompareTo(OtherString), isn't a member of string or string.h, I only can use compare()... but the result is different what I need. 
I work with C++ (VS 2012).

Comment: I wouldn't use the C++ standard library's locale support, since IMHO it's unreliable, complex, inefficient, incomplete and even incompatible with common text representations. Why not just use the .NET stuff. Since you're using .NET.

Comment: I tested with CLR program (with String::Compare) and native program (string::compare) and the output are the same (-1).

Comment: The standard C++ library is just not fit to the task.  You need a library, ICU is a very common choice.